# jsf facelets and http post

Tags: http, jsf, soap, facelets

I have made a web application in jsf that works by the book. I used facelets for presentation with many backing beans and JPA for DB access, now i have a requirement that concerns HTTP messages. Namely i receive from routers periodically SOAP messages about their status as a content of a HTTP POST request. This request is not related to my clients communication with my website, and it is a regular POST message with soap message as its content, and no path to resources in header.

Example:

`POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: something
Content-Length: 23149
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:ddce"
Connection: close`

My SOAP message is here

---

I need to display that message to my clients that are on the website with something like premefaces push technology or similar, but the problem is i don't know how my faces servlet can respond to receiving this message and forward it to managed beans. Should i make a custom servlet and connect it with my faces servlet or can faces servlet be configured to respond to this post request on the same port my clients request webpages.

Any advice would be welcome

Comment: You could start doing a custom Servlet, this servlet could send data to an @ApplicationScoped bean. Once you have this data, you could use the push method of course!